# How do I do a floating-point modulo operation in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

`%` isn't defined. `modulo` only works on integers. I want something equivalent to Javascript's modulo / c's fmod.

Comment: You're asking scheme-specific questions here; please keep your tags minimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the javascript equivalent, I believe, where n=dividend, d=divisor:

```
(let ((nOverD (/ n d)))
      (let ((q (if (> nOverD 0.0) (floor nOverD) (ceiling nOverD))))
        (- n (* d q))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know scheme, but mathematically you could do something like:

```
rem = num - trunc(num / mod) * mod;
```

So for a number like 2.5 mod 2 you would get:

```
2.5 - trunc(2.5 / 2) * 2
= 2.5 - trunc(1.25) * 2
= 2.5 - 1 * 2
= 2.5 - 2
= 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

The [flonum](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-12.html#node_sec_11.3) library defines `flmod`, which does what you want. In Pilot Scheme:

```
(require rnrs/arithmetic/flonums-6)
(flmod pi (sqrt 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to normalize angle to fit between -π and π, then you can do it like this:

```
(angle (make-polar 1 x))
```

Otherwise, you can scale your arguments:

```
(define (mod* x y)
  (let* ((pi (* 4 (atan 1)))
         (c (/ y pi))
         (result (angle (make-polar 1 (/ x c)))))
    (* (+ result (if (negative? result) pi 0)) c)))
```

I'm not sure how the function should behave for negative arguments, so I didn't consider them.

Answer (score 0):

The `mod` function seems to take integers, rationals and floating point numbers (e.g. in petite chez scheme):

```
> (mod 10 4.5)
1.0
> (mod 5.5 1.4)
1.3000000000000007
> (mod 5.5 2/3)
0.16666666666666696
```

If you want operations that only take a floating point number, called a "flonum" in scheme and you're using a r6rs compliant scheme, there are a bunch of flonum operations defined in the library, including `flmod`, e.g.:

```
> (flmod 5. 4.)
1.0
> (flmod 5. 4.5)
0.5
> (flmod 10. 4.5)
1.0
> (flmod 10 4.5)
Exception in flmod: 10 is not a flonum
```

The above was run in chez scheme.

For flonum operations, see section 11.3 on page 46 of [1]

[1] http://www.r6rs.org/final/r6rs-lib.pdf

Answer (score -1):

It looks like remainder is the word you want.  From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Numerical-operations.html):

```
(remainder -13 -4.0)      -1.0
```

Comment: it seems to not take floating point args as the 1st argument, still